# CMake - Copy DLLs to the runtime output directory

Tags: qt, visual-c++, cmake

I am trying to create a simple CMake that retrieves the DLLs of Qt and copy it in the directory in which cmake creates my executable.

It works great using g++ or clang, but MSVC (Visual Studio 2017) creates a *Debug* or *Release* directory.

I can't find a way to retrieve the path to the real directory in which the executable is written (`${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` returns the directory parent of *Release* or *Debug*).

I've seen people using the target property `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` but it is empty when I use it.

Any idea how I can do this ? I do not want to change the output directory, I just want to know its path (so I do not want to change the value of `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio, during *configuration* step (when `CMakeLists.txt` files are processed) [build type](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) is **not set**, so no *build-type*-dependent variable or property is usable directly. Instead, [generator-expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) should be used.

E.g., **output directory** for executable or library target can be extracted with `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:tgt>` generator expression. It will return full directory, with "Release/" or "Debug/" already appended.

Note, that generator expressions can be used only when their usage is *explicitly* allowed in documentation. E.g., they cannot be used in `message()` command.

Alternatively, you may explicitely set variable [CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html), so for every build type will just append appropriate subdirectory to it. But for extracting this subdirectory, you should again resort to generator expressions: `$<CONFIG>`.

---

Technically, it is possible to set the same output directory for any build type. But this is not recommended, because a file from one build type will be *overwritten* by the file from another build type.

Answer (score 1):

Example for Visual Studio 2022 and CMake.

Place this at the end of CMakeLists.txt:

```
if (WIN32)
  add_custom_command(
    TARGET qcpp POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/external/c.dll" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
  )
endif()
```

See [list of CMake variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html).

Note the "qcpp" in the preceding command. This is the project name and should match this line at the start:

```
project ("qcpp")
```

### Appendix A - Testing

To verify, if you generate a Visual Studio Project using `mkdir x && cd x && cmake  ..`, you can see that CMake has added a post-build step to the solution config:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of CMake 3.21+, the `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:tgt>` generator expression can help copy dependent DLLs to the build tree. Quoting the documentation:

> List of DLLs that the target depends on at runtime. This is determined by the locations of all the `SHARED` and `MODULE` targets in the target's transitive dependencies. Using this generator expression on targets other than executables, `SHARED` libraries, and `MODULE` libraries is an error. On non-DLL platforms, it evaluates to an empty string.
>
> This generator expression can be used to copy all of the DLLs that a target depends on into its output directory in a `POST_BUILD` custom command.

Docs link: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS

An example of how to use this (adapted from the docs) follows:

```
find_package(foo REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE foo::foo)

if (WIN32)
  add_custom_command(
    TARGET main POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
            $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:main> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:main>
    COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
  )
endif ()
```

The `if (WIN32)` check ensures that `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:main>` won't be empty, which would cause the command to fail (rather than do nothing). `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` makes sure that the semicolon-delimited list returned by `$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:main>` will be split into multiple arguments, rather than passed as a single argument with (escaped) semicolons in it.

Note also that `UNKNOWN` libraries will be ignored by this generator expression. These are common when using the built-in Find modules, rather than using a library's first-party CMake config-mode package. In these cases, you will have to manually inspect the module variables to find the library paths and add custom commands for each one yourself.

For Qt specifically, I would expect the newer CMake integration in Qt6 to "just work", though I haven't tested it. It might also work in Qt5, but again I haven't tested it.